# Changing\viewing remote Git repo address in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

Can I, via Visual Studio 2013, view and\or change the remote repo or do I **have** to resort to the command line?

Comment: Not sure how to do it in Visual Studio, but the command line usage is extremely simple, just do `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 0):

I could say, you cant view or change the remote repository.
The TFS homepage (online) give a codereview feature only.

You can use team resource manager which is a inner-packed git command
（changes，branches，sync..）

Only Local repository, you can operate.